# Saved a configuration value from admin, but it is still showing the old value after page load

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I am trying to change the UPS type in Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods from Magento admin panel. The current value is United Parcel Service XML

[image]

When I change it to United Parcel Service and click on save

[image]

then after page load it still shows the old value i.e United Parcel Service XML. Value after page load

[image]

I tried clearing cache but still it is showing the old value.

Could anyone help me understand the reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try once with below,

1. fix permissions of folder and files
2. clear and flush cache

> var/cache var/page-cache

3. check with re-deploy the site once